# Perforce (P4) Python API complains about too many locks

Tags: python, perforce

I wrote an application that opens several subprocesses, which initiate connections individually to a Perforce server. After a while I get this error message in almost all of these child-processes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/peter/Desktop/test_app/main.py", line 76, in p4_execute
    p4.run_login()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/P4.py", line 665, in run_login
    return self.run("login", *args, **kargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/P4.py", line 611, in run
    raise e
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/P4.py", line 605, in run
    result = P4API.P4Adapter.run(self, *flatArgs)
P4.P4Exception: [P4#run] Errors during command execution( "p4 login" )

    [Error]: "Fatal client error; disconnecting!
            Operation 'client-SetPassword' failed.
            Too many trys to get lock /Users/peter/.p4tickets.lck."
```

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? I open my connections properly and all double checked on all source locations that I disconnect from the server properly via `disconnect`.

Only deleting the .p4tickets.lck manually works until the error comes back after a few seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant code is here:

- https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce_software-p4/files/2018-1/support/ticket.cc#200
- https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce_software-p4/files/2018-1/sys/filetmp.cc#147

I can't see that there's any code path where the ticket.lck file would fail to get cleaned up without throwing some other error.

Is there anything unusual about the home directory where the tickets file lives?  Like, say, it's on a network filer with some latency and some kind of backup process?  Or maybe one that doesn't properly enforce file locks between all these subprocesses you're spawning?

How often are your scripts running "p4 login" to refresh and re-write the ticket?  Many times a second?  If you change them to not do that (e.g. only login if there's not already a ticket) does the problem persist?

Comment: You are my hero! On each connection (hundreds of times) it executed `run_login`+`connect` which was obviously unnecessary! Thanks a lot

Comment: Aha!  I wouldn't be surprised if there's some kind of race condition there (although it might be that it's theoretically prevented by local file locks and there's an `flock()` problem at play here); under "normal" usage a client isn't running concurrent `login` commands at all, never mind quickly enough for those writes to be happening concurrently.

Comment: For anyone else reading this.. I executed p4.run_login and p4.connect in the same connection method. Only calling `connect` with the credentials is sufficient